# delete uploaded file

Tags: functions, uploads, filesystem

I have a function wp_handle_upload() for uploads files.

```
$file = $_FILES['attachment_icon-' . $i];
$upload = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
```

what is a function for delete a uploaded file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `wp_delete_attachment( $post_id )` if you have used `wp_insert_attachment()` before.
`$post_id` is the attachment ID.

If you haven’t used `wp_insert_attachment()` a simple …

```
unlink( $upload['file'] );
```

… will do it.

Comment: wp_delete_attachment does not remove the file if it was not added via wp_handle_upload. It was added using wp_insert_attachment, but it was uploaded beforehand via file_put_contents (file received in base64). Should I just use unlink then? But then relations in DB will stay for old files?

Comment: In my case I verify that the file is actually removed from the file system but a reference to the file remains in the media library list. Please read this question about it https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321595/why-after-a-file-is-programmatically-deleted-is-there-still-a-reference-in-the

Answer (score 3):

there is no designated WP function, simply because you already have a PHP one, with the following syntax:

```
    <?php
    $filename="MyFile.txt"
    unlink($filename);
    ?>
```

for full doc see the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: This would leave dead entries in the database if it is already registered.