# Why after a file is programmatically deleted, is there still a reference in the media library?

Tags: plugin-development

I work on a plugin that gets a file uploaded to the upload folder through media. The file is processed if it does not meet x condition the process is aborted and the file is deleted.

The deletion is effective when invoking unlink in this way

```
if ($counter === 0) {
    printMessage('No need to process');

    if (unlink($file)) {
        printMessage('File removed');
    }

    return;
}
```

Here `$file` is a reference to `wp_handle_upload` `$upload['file']`

My case is that after verifying that the file has indeed been deleted from the file system, there is a reference to it in the media library.

[image]

I appreciate your comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you upload a file to Media Library, some data (mainly metadata like title, description, and so on) is stored in database.

So if you delete file using `unlink`, you don't delete any rows from DB - so the attachment will be still visible in Media Library.

If you want to delete attachment from ML, you should use WP functions. [`wp_delete_attachment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) might come in handy.

You can use it like so:

```
<?php wp_delete_attachment( <ID_OF_YOUR_ATTACHMENT> ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is clear to me now the reason. How do I get this ID? Currently I get the file information using the `wp_handle_upload` function but in the return values ​​I only have $file, $url and $type.

Comment: I just tried https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/ function but I always get in return 0. I am expecting an ID in this way but no success `$id = attachment_url_to_postid($upload['url']);` `$id` is always 0